# Smart contract using WETH

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, smart-contract-wallets

I am looking for info regarding WETH and what it allows.  From what I understand, by using WETH a smart contract is able to process payment while the user is "offline".  In other words, a user commit a certain amount of WETH from a wallet and then the smart contract will process that later.  And this is the only way to have any sort of offline payment.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

WETH is "Wrapped ETH". WETH by itself does not provide the kinds of functions you are talking about. However, generally speaking, once the ETH is wrapped in an ERC20 wrapper (such as WETH), you can use ERC20 functionality to implement more complex behaviors like the ones you are describing. Of course, if that functionality is proprietary there's no need to wrap the ETH in an ERC20, it could be owned by a contract that has any interface you desire.

Beyond this kind of general answer, the answer to your question is simply "no." :)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes after a bit of research I think I understand.  The approve interface for ERC20 allows a contract to do the type of thing I am talking about, right?  And ethereum is not ERC20, so you wrap it in WETH which is ERC20. Do I have that right?